# Tell me before I start editing that I can't suggest edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, ios-app

On sites where I don't have the edit privilege, the iOS app still lets me make all the improvements I want to a post, but won't let me submit them:

[image]

Could the app warn me with this message before I spend a bunch of time editing the post?

Comment: @Shokhet That post is a bug report that the app can't suggest edits, this one is a request that I get the error earlier in the process.

Comment: Alright, then. ....I agree that would be useful, +1.